# Unable to make phone calls or send text message because of "call barring"

Tags: sms, calls, samsung-galaxy-s-10

There is nothing wrong with my sim card nor the providers of it. However I am unable to call anyone or send text messages to anyone but I am able to receive calls and text messages from anyone.

Whenever I try to call someone I get the following message "Can't make outgoing calls while call barrng is on"

What I have tried: entered phone app -> Settings -> Supplementary services -> Call barring -> Voice call. Everything is unchecked! If I check everything, nothing changes about my situation I am still unable to call people

I am on Samsung Galaxy S10 Plus

Answer (score 0):

Back up all your important files and start a new. Create a Smart switch back up and factory reset. Smart switch could possibly be backing up the file that's giving you fits. Maybe don't backup anything phone related too.